# PHP: reading a PDF and obtaining the position of a specific word (tag)

Tags: php, laravel, image, pdf, fpdf

I have a Laravel 5.6.39 project with a working esignature solution using these packages:

*"codedge/laravel-fpdf": "^1.3",

"setasign/fpdi": "^2.2",

"setasign/fpdi-fpdf": "^2.2"*

But this works only with a fixed position of last page, bottom right. What I need to achieve is:

- read the PDF
- find a word (like SIGNATURE etc.)
- get the coordinates for that word
- use these coordinates in the already prepared image insertion func.

  ```
  // use the imported page and adjust the page size
  $pdf->useTemplate($templateId, ['adjustPageSize' => true]);
  if ( $pageNo == $pageCount ) {
      $fullname = iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-2',$client->name).' '.iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-2',$client->lastname);
      $pdf->Image(public_path('storage/signatures/resized/'.$signature->signature_image), 115, 255, 50, '', '', '', '', false, 400);
      $pdf->AddFont('Arial','','arial.php');
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial');
      $pdf->SetXY(115, 263); //fixed coordinates, I need X,Y for word tag
      $pdf->Write(10, $fullname.' '.date('d.m.Y'));
  }
  ```

Has anyone done something like this and could give some advice on it?

I am reading up on SetaPDF-Extractor (https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/details/) and it might be the thing that I need but I need to be sure of this before purchasing it.

Comment: So just go ahead and request an evaluation version of the SetaPDF-Extractor component [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/evaluate/) before purchasing it. Your task is not possible with FPDF/FPDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was done nicely with SetaPDF-Extractor. Tried the evaluation, bought the license and had good results in an hour.